# Reloading page in background without alert() (using sweetalert instead)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sweetalert

I have a php function which reloads one page in hidden iframe before real redirection is done after input button is clicked.

```
function button_confirm_order_params() {
  $url = "somepagetoreloadinbackground.php";
  $alert = "alert('you will be redirected to ext. page')";
  return "onclick=\"document.all.myFrame.src='$url'; $alert;\"";
}
```

Everything works good, however I would like to use something more beautiful than browser's alert. So I downloaded SweetAlert and changed *return* to:

```
 return "id=\"btnShowAlert\" onclick=\"document.all.myFrame.src='$url'; \"";
```

The problem is that without alert() the page is not being stopped before redirection. It's just shows sweetalert for a moment and then opens another page, so my "somepagetoreloadinbackground.php" is not loaded. Any ideas to handle it?

Comment: EIther use a timeout to set how long the alert should be shown, or have the alert closing be the event that triggers the url change instead of the click on the button.

Comment: Adding timeout doesn't work. I think it's not about sweetalert, it's more about that typical alert() as input tag stops redirecting. Without it, it goes through. Question is, if I can get around of it by any way.

Comment: A classic alert is a blocking function, so it stops all other javascript execution until the alert has been clicked away. Without the alert, the code keeps running and immediately redirects to the new page. So you have to 'simulate' this waiting time by either not having any more JS on the call stack (by using a callback) or by using a timeout so that the redirect functin gets deferred to a later time. Can you show some more code? The function you show only returns some html string, but could you show how the redirect actually happens?

Comment: Thanks for your help.
It's a part of osCommerce shop engine. This is a part which generates button confirm with $button_params sended by code above.
`  if (method_exists($GLOBALS[$payment_modules->selected_module], `'button_confirm_order_params')) {
`    $button_params = `$GLOBALS[$payment_modules->selected_module]->button_confirm_ord`` er_params();
`  } else {
`    $button_params = '';
`  }
`  echo tep_image_submit('button_confirm_order.gif', `IMAGE_BUTTON_CONFIRM_ORDER, $button_params) . "\n";

Comment: I handled to show the alert through the jQuery (on id which is shown in my first post),

Comment: However, I dont have an idea, how to use another options to get it work
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnShowAlert").click(function(){
            alert("The paragraph is now hidden");
    });
});

Answer (score 0):

If you check the examples given on a sweetalert github, it seems there's actually alot of options that can help you: http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/

There's a standard timeout version: It's the timer attribute you have to add.

```
swal({
  title: "some title",
  text: "some message",
  timer: 2000, // timeout in miliseconds
  showConfirmButton: false // show ok button or not
});
```

And also, although it's a confirm instead of an alert, there's a callback function! Just add you redirect to that callback if the timeout version isn't good enough:

```
swal({
    // add all options you want
},
function(){
    // the actual callback, triggered by clicking the ok button on the confirm.
    document.all.myFrame.src='$url'
});
```

Always read the docs for the library you're using first. :)

Comment: The problem is that everything works if it's in local. For example, I can make sth like this:

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
    $("#btnShowAlert").click(function() {
        swal({ 
      title: "text",
       text: "text",
        type: "success"
      },
      function(){
          alert( "hello" );
    });
    });
    });
    
    </script>
But if I will put it as the part of whole engine it won't show an alert, only swal message for a moment.

Comment: So the callback of swal is never triggered? Does it give any errors? Tbh, I don't understand any more what you're trying to do. Why should the page in the frame (somepagetoreloadinbackground.php) be loaded and then a few seconds later be gone again when the redirect to the next page happens? What does that page actually do in that short time? I'm starting to think this might be a logical / structural issue instead.